# Graphics hardware acceleration error

Tags: graphics-card

I'm having a Desktop PC with Intel i3 CPU with 4GB of RAM on a Gigabit mother board. I'm not an extreme gamer but even the Spider Solitaire is not showing properly saying "**hardware acceleration is either disabled or not supported by your video card...**". Can someone please suggest what piece of hardware (such as a graphics card i guess) I'm missing on my PC?

I have no knowledge of hardware. So please excuse me for any mistakes.

Comment: This is usually do to a driver not installed for video - Do you have a video card installed or are you using on-board video?

Comment: I'm able to play videos on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install [Intel HD graphics driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81502/Intel-HD-Graphics-2000-for-2nd-Generation-Intel-Core-Processors) in place of "Standard VGA Graphics" and it got better now. At least the Spider Solitaire and Windows Media Center are opening smoothly. Thank you all :)

Answer (score -1):

All modern computers come with a graphics card otherwise you would not be able to see any output. Without knowing your exact PC specifications I cannot give specific advice.

It sounds like you haven't got the correct drivers for your graphics hardware installed. You can check and update your graphics drivers by doing the following:

1. Press [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) key and [r](/questions/tagged/r) together to get the run dialog
2. Enter `devmgmt.msc` and hit ok, this opens the device manager for your PC and lists all the hardware currently installed
3. Expand the display adapters option, your graphics card should be listed

[image: Windows device manager]

4. Double click on it to show the device properties
5. Click on the **Driver** tab

[image: Driver properties]

6. Click **Update Driver**
7. Choose **Search Automatically** it will download and install the latest drivers registered with Microsoft

[image: Windows driver search]

8. While that is running your screen may flicker black a few times, **this is normal**. It is Windows unloading the old driver and installing the new one.
9. Once this process has finished, close all the windows and restart your PC.

There are two types of graphics device, onboard and expansion cards. Expansion cards are a LOT more powerful than the onboard versions.

Comment: Answer needs a small fix: no such thing as onboard graphics cards - an oxymoron. In your example screenshot you show Intel 4600HD graphics. These are not on a card OR entirely on the motherboard. They are actually part of the CPU. If you dropped a different CPU in there you could have a different integrated graphics capability. Only the connector lies on the board, modern Intel CPUs do all of the processing in the CPU. Some chips even include an amount of extra dedicated E-DRAM on the CPU for graphics.

Comment: Given the apparent lack of knowledge demonstrated by the questioner I felt a more detailed explanation of the technical aspects of graphics cards would not be helpful. I'll edit my answer if you think I should add in a more technical answer.

Comment: @DavidVernon - What?  Your comments holds almost no technical merit to it.

Comment: Happy to take this to chat. For Intel, the motherboard chipset determines CPU family and therefore iGPU family. For example your choice of Intel CPU determines whether you have a 5000 or 5200 iGPU, but you can't get a 6000 series CPU and iGPU on an older board. Integrated GPUs are exactly that, built into the CPU. And some CPUs include a small DRAM package dedicated to graphics (see Iris Pro).m I stand by my other statement. Yes there is such a thing as onboard graphics, but not an onboard graphics card, which is an oxymoron.

Comment: I have tweaked the wording to be a little more neutral. While @DavidVernon is correct with regards to the technical nature of graphics hardware. In the context of the OP I saw no benefit in explaining this as it would probably confuse and not help the OP.

Comment: Thank you @Burgi. I just followed the given steps and found "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" under "Display" and when I tried to update the driver, it says the driver software is up to date but did not solve the problem. Can you please recommend any other solution?

Comment: Do you know the make and model of your motherboard?